# SQL Add summary row for all days with same id

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have the following results table from this query but how can we add a summary row to sum all of the days for the same ad id, as seen in the desired results table?  Thanks.

Query:

```
SELECT
  right(ad_id,6) AS ad_id,
  CAST(date_start AS DATE) AS "Day",
  objective,
  SUM(impressions) AS Impressions,
  sum(clicks) AS Clicks
FROM ads 
WHERE date_start >= '2018-05-01' AND date_start < '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY ad_id, CAST(date_start AS DATE), objective
Order by ad_id, CAST(date_start AS DATE) desc
```

Results table:

```html
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| ad_id  |   day    |  objective  | impressions | clicks |
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  36911 | 5/2/2018 | CONVERSIONS |       16689 |    160 |
|  36911 | 5/1/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        4223 |     59 |
|  37111 | 5/2/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        1964 |      9 |
|  37111 | 5/1/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        1409 |     19 |
| 279311 | 5/3/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |         309 |     10 |
| 279311 | 5/2/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        2816 |     19 |
| 279311 | 5/1/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        5876 |     66 |
| 279511 | 5/3/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        3551 |     86 |
| 279511 | 5/2/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        3334 |     76 |
| 279511 | 5/1/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |       17798 |    508 |
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

Desired results table with summary row:

```html
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| ad_id  |   day    |  objective  | impressions | clicks |
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  36911 | All      | CONVERSIONS |       20912 |    219 |
|  36911 | 5/2/2018 | CONVERSIONS |       16689 |    160 |
|  36911 | 5/1/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        4223 |     59 |
|  37111 | All      | CONVERSIONS |        3373 |     28 |
|  37111 | 5/2/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        1964 |      9 |
|  37111 | 5/1/2018 | CONVERSIONS |        1409 |     19 |
| 279311 | All      | LINK_CLICKS |        9001 |     95 |
| 279311 | 5/3/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |         309 |     10 |
| 279311 | 5/2/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        2816 |     19 |
| 279311 | 5/1/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        5876 |     66 |
| 279511 | All      | LINK_CLICKS |       24683 |    670 |
| 279511 | 5/3/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        3551 |     86 |
| 279511 | 5/2/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |        3334 |     76 |
| 279511 | 5/1/2018 | LINK_CLICKS |       17798 |    508 |
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: In addition to the Subtotals, can we add a Total row at the top that sums up all the line items? So, for Clicks, the total is 1012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(right(ad_id, 6), 'All') AS ad_id,
       CAST(date_start AS DATE) AS "Day",
       objective,
       SUM(impressions) AS Impressions,
       sum(clicks) AS Clicks
FROM ads 
WHERE date_start >= '2018-05-01' AND date_start < '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (ad_id), (ad_id, CAST(date_start AS DATE), objective) )
Order by ad_id, CAST(date_start AS DATE) desc;
```

In earlier versions of Postgres, use a CTE and `union all`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT right(ad_id, 6) AS ad_id,
             CAST(date_start AS DATE) AS "Day",
             objective,
             SUM(impressions) AS Impressions,
             sum(clicks) AS Clicks
      FROM ads 
      WHERE date_start >= '2018-05-01' AND date_start < '2018-06-01'
      GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ad_id, CAST(date_start AS DATE), objective)
     )
select *
from t
union all
select ad_id, NULL, 'All', sum(impressions), sum(clicks)
from t
group by ad_id
order by 1, 2 desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, @ Gordon Linoff.  I ran it and got this error: Syntax error at or near "Sets".  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @LeoJones . . . `GROUPING SETS` are definitely part of Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).  They were introduced in 9.5, which was several years ago.

Comment: We are using postgreSQL 8.0.2.  Is there an equivalent function?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, the CTE is working like a charm (after removing Grouping Sets since postgresql 8.0 does not support it and we can't upgrade due to using Amazon Redshift).  Thank you so much!